# AlarmManager vs Service for db and FTP connection. Which and how to use?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, wakelock, wakeup

My question is rather simple but might come with a complex answer.

I'm making an App that checks on an online mysql db (via a php script on the website) for new updates. Sometimes this updates will tell the App it has to download form a FTP server.

The App should start on boot and check for updates every 15 minutes.

I've read in the web I should either use a service or a AlarmManager but I don't know which one is better.

Also, I've read a lot of pages that say that AlarmManager will "Wake Up" the device but I've failed to understand what this really means and why it's different in a service. Does this means that if the Phone is turned off it will turn it on or that it will turn on the screen?

I only need the phone to do the task in the background when it's on, I don't need it to turn the screen on or power up the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've read in the web I should either use a service or a AlarmManager but I don't know which one is better.

It's not an "or". It's an "and". You will need to use `AlarmManager` to trigger the work to be done by a `Service`.

> I've read a lot of pages that say that AlarmManager will "Wake Up" the device but I've failed to understand what this really means

An `AlarmManager` `_WAKEUP` event type (e.g., `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`) will wake up the device out of sleep mode. That, in conjunction with something like `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and an `IntentService`, can arrange for you to do your work periodically even though the device would ordinarily be asleep (screen and CPU in a sleep state).

> I only need the phone to do the task in the background when it's on, I don't need it to turn the screen on or power up the device.

Then you can use `AlarmManager` with a non-`_WAKEUP` alarm type (e.g., `ELAPSED_REALTIME`). I would still recommend using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and an `IntentService`, to make sure that the device does not fall asleep in the middle of what you are doing, as that may cause problems for your work.

Comment: So far I was trying to make an event every 15 minutes with AlarmManager that fired a AsynkTask with opened the xxx.com/xxx.php  and then if needed open a FTP conection in the same AsynkTask. I'm starting to understand this is a bad idea, it could be interrupted?

Comment: @LucianoStupenengo: "with AlarmManager that fired a AsynkTask" -- that is not possible. `AlarmManager` invokes a `PendingIntent`, which will either start an activity, start a service, or send a broadcast. It cannot directly run an `AsyncTask`. "it could be interrupted?" -- the device can fall asleep or the process could be terminated. Using a `Service` (such as an `IntentService`) would help avoid the process termination scenario. Using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` will help with the device falling asleep scenario.

Comment: Ok now, I think you've set me in the right path. I have the AlarmManager and I'm reading how to use WakefullBroadcasReceiver, then once I undestand this I'll use an IntentService to make open my PHP and FTP.

Comment: @LucianoStupenengo: FWIW, here is a sample project demonstrating the use of `AlarmManager, `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, and `IntentService`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast